# How to load only the most recent file from a directory where the filenames endswith the date?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, glob

I have files in one directory/folder named:

1. `sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type_2022-04-30.csv`
2. `sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type_2022-05-31.csv`
3. `sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type_2022-06-30.csv`
4. `sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type_2022-07-31.csv`
5. `sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type_2022-08-31.csv`

The folder will be updated with each month's file in the same format as above. e.g.

- `sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type_2022-09-30.csv`
- `sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type_2022-10-31.csv`

I want to only load the most recent month's .csv into a pandas dataframe, not all the files. How can I do this (maybe using glob)?

code below get the most file by metadat loading date but not the string of the filename

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*') # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_file)
```

**Note** there are other file in the same directory with different prefixes.

Comment: You have a list, you can [sort it](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) to get the most recent.

Comment: You can just omit the "key" argument for "max".

Answer (score 1):

If all files have the same prefix, then all you need to do is get the last file in the sorted list of names, since ISO 8601 date strings are lexicographically comparable:

```
import glob
import os

list_of_files = sorted(glob.glob('/path/to/folder/.csv*'))
latest_file = list_of_files[-1]
print(latest_file)
```

In fact, just

```
latest_file = max(glob.glob('/path/to/folder/.csv*'))
```

works too, if you don't need the full list for anything.

Comment: what if there are other csv's in the same folder? i.e there are other file with different prefixes?

Comment: If you only care about a single prefix, then filter the list first, e.g. with a list comprehension: `list_of_matching_files = [path for path in glob.glob("...") if "sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type_" in path]`.

Comment: (Or, of course, you can do that filtering right in `glob`: `glob.glob("/path/to/folder/sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type_*.csv")`...)

Comment: what if we care about the suffix i.e. original file is like "2022-09-30_sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_type.csv". Does the logic change or does it still hold true

Comment: Should work just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposition to select the most recent file by the filename using [**`pathlib`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

dir_files = r'/path/to/folder/*'

dico={}

for file in Path(dir_files).glob('sacoronavirus_total_number_vaccinated_*.csv'):
    dico[file.stem.split('_')[-1]] = file

max_date = max(dico) # There is no need to parse ISO 8601 dates
```

Then, you can use [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and pass the file path to create a dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv(dico[max_date])
```

Comment: There is no need to parse an ISO 8601 YYYY-MM-DD string to sort it.

Comment: ... or to use `fromisoformat`, which parses it. :)